# Angular material pop up is not coming after putting it on my entry components array

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to show angular material dialog box when the user press the back button with some style and data inside it. Initially when I have not put the `BackButtonPressedComponent` in my `entryComponents array` then the pop up window was coming and I was getting an error that I should add it in entryComponents array but when I have added it then I can not see any pop up window at all. what could be the reason behind this?
below my relevent code

```
      constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    this.getPaymentSummaryData();
    this.location.subscribe(
      x => {
  console.log(x);
  if (x.type === 'popstate') {
console.log('data is ' + this.paymentList.length);
const str = String(this.paymentList.length);
console.log(str);

// confirm('<h1>Are you sure?</h1><br>' + str + 'are in queue, awaiting decision.');
      let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BackButtonPressedComponent, {
       width: "500px",
      //  data: { payment: this.paymentList }
      });
  console.log(dialogRef);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log("The dialog was closed");
        console.log(result);
      });

  }
      }
  );
  }
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: No. now the error is gone since I have added it in my entryComponents array.